# Como retornar as 10 primeiras linhas de uma tabela do postegres em python?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Por favor, como faço para retornar em python (flask_sqlalchemy) os 10 primeros registros de 3 colunas específicas (como 'street', 'postcode' e 'city') da tabela? Já tentei com for e trocando o query.all() por query.first(10)... quando pesquiso sobre o tema para saber o que fazer só aparece resultados de trazer um elemento específico ou em linguagem SQL. Como estou começando, não sei como pesquisar corretamente. Obrigada

```
from flask import Flask, Response, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = True
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'postgresql://postgres:123@localhost:5432/db_coordinates'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class TbFirstBase(db.Model):
    id_first_base = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    lat = db.Column(db.String, unique=False, nullable=False)
    lng = db.Column(db.String, unique=False, nullable=False)
    street = db.Column(db.String, unique=False, nullable=False)
    postcode = db.Column(db.String, unique=False, nullable=False)
    city = db.Column(db.String, unique=False, nullable=False)
    country = db.Column(db.String, unique=False, nullable=False)

    def to_json(self):
        return {"id_first_base": self.id_first_base,
                "lat": self.lat,
                "lng": self.lng,
                "street": self.street,
                "postccode": self.postcode,
                "city": self.city,
                "country": self.country}


# CRUD---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Select All
@app.route("/tb_first_base", methods=["GET"])
def selection_adresses():
    tb_first_base_list = TbFirstBase.query.all()
    tb_first_base_json = [tb_first_base.to_json() for tb_first_base in tb_first_base_list]
    return generate_response(200, "tb_first_base", tb_first_base_json)
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você deseja apenas trazer essas três **colunas** e com **limit** substitua:

```
tb_first_base_list = TbFirstBase.query.all()
```

Por:

```
tb_first_base_list = TbFirstBase.query.with_entities(TbFirstBase.street, TbFirstBase.postcode, TbFirstBase.city).limit(10)
```

e depois retorne em forma de Json caso desejar!